# how to write echo output into a text file in jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins

Im trying to write echo output to a text file within the command itself. Im running this script on jenkins built-in controller itself which is windows machine. Here is my code,

pipeline {
agent any

```
stages {
    stage('Hello') {
        steps {
            echo 'Hello World'
        }
    }
}
```

}

In this code, Im trying to write the echo output to a text file from the same command.
For example, echo 'Hello World' >Helloworld.txt

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that you can do just one command. you may have to script and output with one and write with the other.

Use the `[writeFile][1]` step. It's a basic, included step with the pipeline plugin.

```
script {
// first set a var
text = "Hello world"
// print it
echo '$text'
// write the file
writeFile(
    'file': 'Helloworld.txt',
    'text': '$text'
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `bat`(sh - linux/bat - windows) command

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Hello') {
      steps {
        // Run the 'echo' command using the 'bat' step and redirect the output to the file
        bat 'echo Hello World > Helloworld.txt'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but still better way would be `writeFile` [link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace)